# What material is superconductor at 394 K and 2 Mega Pascals?

Tags: pressure, temperature, electric-current, superconductivity

What material is superconductor (high current) at 394 K and 2 Mega Pascals?

Comment: Do you realise that is about 121 Celsius? If you meant -394 K then nothing can get that cold since absolute zero is about -273 K.

Answer (score 1):

As per [WikiPedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room-temperature_superconductor), as of 2020,

*A room-temperature superconductor is a material that is capable of exhibiting superconductivity at operating temperatures above 0 °C (273 K; 32 °F), that is, temperatures that can be reached and easily maintained in an everyday environment. As of 2020 the material with the highest accepted superconducting temperature is an extremely pressurized carbonaceous sulfur hydride with a critical transition temperature of +15°C at 267 GPa*.

So to answer your question, nothing yet has been found to be superconducting at $394 K$ ($\approx 121 C$) even under $2 MPa$ pressure (which by today’s standards, not the lowest possible pressure.